# Updating path for OS environment

Tags: path, operating-system, environment

## Before you proceed, update the PATH

import os
os.environ['PATH'] = f"{os.environ['PATH']}:/root/.local/bin"
os.environ['PATH'] = f"{os.environ['PATH']}:/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages"

i am new to coding, how do i go about updating this?